# Moving objects collision Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

My collision of moving objects is not working. I have created a demo so you can see it and see my problem all code and everything included.

As you may be able to see, I have 2 blocks coming from left to right and then I have a tank shooting bullets> I tried in all kind of directions and I always get the same results, basically my collision only works the velocity of the blocks value, in the example on the zip file only works up to 300px. Depending on the blocks speed, if I change the block speed to a greater number then the collision works on the same numbers pixels. it is really weird.

I was wondering if I'm just doing the whole thing wrong or what could my problem be? I would appreciate any pointers or ideas that can help me solve this issue. Thanks.

[Demo source code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-flkUZkRaeQMmhFOTcwem1LLTQ).

```
BasicGame.Game = function (game) {

    //  When a State is added to Phaser it automatically has the following properties set on it, even if they already exist:

    this.game;      //  a reference to the currently running game (Phaser.Game)
    this.add;       //  used to add sprites, text, groups, etc (Phaser.GameObjectFactory)
    this.camera;    //  a reference to the game camera (Phaser.Camera)
    this.cache;     //  the game cache (Phaser.Cache)
    this.input;     //  the global input manager. You can access this.input.keyboard, this.input.mouse, as well from it. (Phaser.Input)
    this.load;      //  for preloading assets (Phaser.Loader)
    this.math;      //  lots of useful common math operations (Phaser.Math)
    this.sound;     //  the sound manager - add a sound, play one, set-up markers, etc (Phaser.SoundManager)
    this.stage;     //  the game stage (Phaser.Stage)
    this.time;      //  the clock (Phaser.Time)
    this.tweens;    //  the tween manager (Phaser.TweenManager)
    this.state;     //  the state manager (Phaser.StateManager)
    this.world;     //  the game world (Phaser.World)
    this.particles; //  the particle manager (Phaser.Particles)
    this.physics;   //  the physics manager (Phaser.Physics)
    this.rnd;       //  the repeatable random number generator (Phaser.RandomDataGenerator)

    //  You can use any of these from any function within this State.
    //  But do consider them as being 'reserved words', i.e. don't create a property for your own game called "world" or you'll over-write the world reference.

     this.bulletTimer = 0;

};

BasicGame.Game.prototype = {

    create: function () {

                            //Enable physics

// Set the physics system
            this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);


        //End of physics 


        //  Honestly, just about anything could go here. It's YOUR game after all. Eat your heart out!

         this.createBullets();
         this.createTanque();

        this.timerBloques = this.time.events.loop(1500, this.createOnebloque, this);

    },

    update: function () {


        if(this.game.input.activePointer.isDown){
            this.fireBullet();
        }

       this.game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.bullets, this.bloque, this.collisionBulletBloque, null, this);

    },

    createBullets: function() {

    this.bullets = this.game.add.group();
    this.bullets.enableBody = true;
    this.bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
    this.bullets.createMultiple(100, 'bulletSprite');
    this.bullets.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
    this.bullets.setAll('anchor.y', 1);
    this.bullets.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
    this.bullets.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true); 


    },

    fireBullet: function(){ 

   if (this.bulletTimer < this.game.time.time) {
            this.bulletTimer = this.game.time.time + 1400;
            this.bullet = this.bullets.getFirstExists(false);
        if (this.bullet) {
            this.bullet.reset(this.tanque.x, this.tanque.y - 20);
            this.game.physics.arcade.enable(this.bullet);
        this.bullet.enableBody = true;
            this.bullet.body.velocity.y = -800;
            }
        }

    },

    createOnebloque: function(){


        this.bloquecs = ["bloqueSprite","bloquelSprite"];
        this.bloquesr = this.bloquecs[Math.floor(Math.random()*2)];
        this.bloque = this.add.sprite(0, 360, this.bloquesr);
        this.game.physics.arcade.enable(this.bloque);
        this.bloque.enableBody = true;
        this.bloque.body.velocity.x = 300;
        this.bloque.body.kinematic = true;
        this.bloque.checkWorldBounds = true;
        this.bloque.outOfBoundsKill = true;
        this.bloque.body.immovable = true;

    },

        createTanque: function() {

        this.tanqueBounds = new Phaser.Rectangle(0, 600, 1024, 150);

        this.tanque = this.add.sprite(500, 700, 'tanqueSprite');
        this.tanque.inputEnabled = true;
        this.tanque.input.enableDrag(true);
        this.tanque.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5);
        this.tanque.input.boundsRect = this.tanqueBounds;


    },

        collisionBulletBloque: function(bullet, bloque) {


        this.bullet.kill();

    },


    quitGame: function (pointer) {

        //  Here you should destroy anything you no longer need.
        //  Stop music, delete sprites, purge caches, free resources, all that good stuff.

        //  Then let's go back to the main menu.
        this.state.start('MainMenu');

    }

};
```

Comment: Can you space out your paragraphs to make it easier to read. Also, it is better if you post your code here.

Comment: Tried to post code but I guess it is too much and it wont let me sorry :(

Comment: Managed to put the code, this is mainly my whole demo

Comment: `The page you are trying to access is not available for your account.`. Provide a link to JSFiddle.net. Also print your variables on each loop in the console to debug.

Comment: Sorry updated the link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-flkUZkRaeQMmhFOTcwem1LLTQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code definitely helps, but you can actually get an idea of what's happening just from playing the game.

As the blocks are going by you can actually get the bullets to disappear if you fire and hit the right edge of the center-most block.

What's happening is that you're checking for a collision between the bullets and a block, but the block is getting redefined every time you add a new one to the screen on the left.

What you probably want to do is create a pool of blocks (`bloquePool` for example), almost exactly like what you're doing in `createBullets` with your bullet pool (what you've called `bullets`).

Then check for a collision between the group of bullets and the group of blocks.

```
this.game.physics.arcade.overlap(
    this.bullets, this.bloquePool, this.collisionBulletBloque, null, this
);
```

You should get the individual bullet and the individual block that collided passed into `collisionBulletBloque` so you can still kill the bullet as you are.

Comment: Thanks I'm not sure why did I not try that before thanks man you rock :), will try tonight and update.

Comment: Still playing with the groups when I make them groups the images only display as small black boxes.

Comment: If you pull up the console in your browser do you see any errors? That almost sounds like the images aren't loading, but the color is off. You could verify the objects added to your new group are being created correctly.

Comment: Got it all fix physics working like a charm.